# Angular - Table data showing up as NaN on web page

Tags: angular, html-table, components, nan

I've been stuck with this issue for a while. I am simply trying to load a table including Id, Name, and Create Date columns to the page. My API methods are working fine in my Controller class in Visual Studio. I previously had this error in the console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.

This error also appears for `name` if I remove `id` and so on.

I have done some researched and learned that I could use the `?` elvis operator, which I have implemented into my HTML. After implementing the elvis operator, the errors have disappeared, but all of the table values now show as `NaN`. Under Network in Developer Tools, I can click on my table name and view the data is populated in my table.

Any idea what the issue could be? I have included the code below:

test-table-tburns-list.component.html

```
<div>
  <table>
      <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Create Date</th>
      </tr>

      <tr *ngFor="let test-table-tburns of testTableTburnsList">
          <td>{{ test-table-tburns?.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ test-table-tburns?.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ test-table-tburns?.createDate }}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

test-table-tburns-list.component.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';   
import { TestTableTburnsListComponent } from './test-table-tburns-list.component';

describe('TestTableTburnsListComponent', () => {
  let component: TestTableTburnsListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestTableTburnsListComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TestTableTburnsListComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestTableTburnsListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

test-table-tburns-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestTableTburnsApiService } from '../../../services/test-table-tburns-api.service';
import { TestTableTburnsModel } from '../../../models/test-table-tburns-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-table-tburns-list',
  templateUrl: './test-table-tburns-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-table-tburns-list.component.css']
})
export class TestTableTburnsListComponent implements OnInit {
  testTableTburnsList: Array<TestTableTburnsModel>;
  title = "Hello TestTableTburns List";


  constructor(private testTableTburnsApi: TestTableTburnsApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.testTableTburnsApi
    .getTestTableTburns()
    .subscribe(_ => this.testTableTburnsList = _, e => console.log(e));
  }

}
```

test-table-tburns-api.service.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { TestTableTburnsApiService } from './test-table-tburns-api.service';

describe('TestTableTburnsApiService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [TestTableTburnsApiService]
    });
  });

  it('should be created', inject([TestTableTburnsApiService], (service: TestTableTburnsApiService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

test-table-tburns-api.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class TestTableTburnsApiService {

  domain : string;

  constructor(public http: Http){
      this.domain = environment.apiUrl;
  }

  public getTestTableTburns(){
      let uri = this.domain + `/api/test-table-tburns`;

      return this.http
      .get(uri)
      .map((res: Response) => {
          return res.json();
      })
      ;
  }
}
```

Comment: How does the response actually look like? Displaying `NaN` seems very unusual in this case.

Comment: I mean how does the response look like you are receiving? The JSON.

Comment: The response is a 200 'OK'. I don't see any issues with it.

Comment: But what is the JSON response? The data you are receiving :D Copy paste a snippet of your JSON.

Comment: Hopefully I am not getting confused. Is this what you're looking for? This is the data I am receiving:

[{"id":1,"name":"Tyler Burns","createDate":"2018-01-18T15:31:47.12"},{"id":2,"name":"John Smith","createDate":"2018-01-18T15:35:22.333"},{"id":3,"name":"Bob Jones","createDate":"2018-01-18T15:35:22.333"},{"id":4,"name":"Brian Hall","createDate":"2018-01-18T15:35:22.333"},{"id":5,"name":"Amy Cook","createDate":"2018-01-18T15:35:22.333"},{"id":7,"name":"Test User","createDate":"2018-01-22T20:51:55.22"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, that you are using dash, i.e `-` in your `*ngFor`, this is not allowed, since it will be considered as subtraction, therefore Angular correctly points out that the result of the substraction is not a number, aka `NaN`. So use a naming convention without the dash:

```
<tr *ngFor="let test of testTableTburnsList">
  <td>{{test.id}}</td>
</tr>
```

Also in this case, the safe navigation operator is not needed as you are iterating an array, so if `testTableTburnsList` is falsy, it will not try and display the single objects in the array unless there are values.

Comment: Crazy how something so subtle can cause over a day's worth of headaches. Thank you for figuring this out!

Comment: Yeah it took a while for me to see it as well. When I tried your code then I realized :D Have a nice weekend and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

The monadic null check doesn't exist in javascript/typescript. So you can remove those '?' in the template.

The error  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` tell's you that the property  `testTableTburnsList` is an array that's contains at least one item equals to undefined. You should try to add `{{ testTableTburnsList | json }}` in your template in order to understand your issue (probably located in `TestTableTburnsApiService`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I removed the `?` elvis operators from the HTML. I am a little confused on your request to add `{{ testTableTburnsList | json }}`. Could you help me understand that? I added the API service code to my original post. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: With `{{ testTableTburnsList | json }}` in the template you'll be able to look at the actual value of the property `testTableTburnsList`.  Maybe you should instantiate that property to `[]` in the component constructor to avoid it being undefined

Comment: @WilliamKLEIN Using the safe navigation operator is very common in Angular... https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Comment: With `{{ testTableTburnsList | json }}` in the template the table shows 6 rows of null (there are 6 participants in the table). Also, I used the safe navigation operator previously and the table shows NaN where each value should be.